# Linking hunspell with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2022, hunspell

I managed to compile hunspell with Visual Studio and I'm having dificulties making it work.
Here's what I have done:

*Project Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories* and added this line: **C:\src\hunspell\src\hunspell**

*Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories* and added this line: **C:\src\hunspell\msvc\Debug_dll\libhunspell**

I got this error when I try to run:

```
cMain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Hunspell_create referenced in function "public: __thiscall cMain::cMain(class wxString const &,int,class wxPoint const &,class wxSize const &,long)" (??0cMain@@QAE@ABVwxString@@HABVwxPoint@@ABVwxSize@@J@Z)
```

I also copied the *C:\src\hunspell\msvc\Debug_dll\libhunspell\libhunspell.dll* to my \Debug folder.

Anyone can help?
Thank you.

Comment: `Additional Library Directories` usually this is not the correct thing to do. Normally you need to link to libraries in `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`

Comment: @drescherjm I added the C:\src\hunspell\msvc\Debug_dll\libhunspell to the Link->Input->Addittional Dependencies and got some new errors: "link.exe" exited with code 1104 ; cannot open file 'C:\src\hunspell\msvc\Debug\libhunspell.obj'

Comment: Don't you have a `.lib` file? Maybe your file explorer has "Hide extensions for known types" enabled and its confusing you. I recommend turning that off.

Comment: @drescherjm I was using the Debug_dll, but the VS was trying to acess a file in \Debug, but in \Debug there is 3 folders only: hunspell, libhunspell and testparser

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding the **libhunspell.dll** and **libhunspell.lib** to my Resource Files folder.